# How to properly define properties in c++/cli in headers/body

Tags: c++-cli

I am trying to do

```
property double Real;
```

and then

```
double Data::ComplexNumber::Real::get() {
    return _real;
}
```

But it is giving error. How do you go about declaring the methods in the header file and then actually implementing them? Do you use this approach in c++/cli, or you'll go the c#/vb.net way of declaring the classes and implementing right there everything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, this seems to work:

Put the following in the property definition:

```
property double Real { double get(); void set(double value); }
```

Comment: As I recall it, your initial attempt just creates a member + a full property get/set implementation, so your implementation of Real::get would clash with the compiler-generated one.

Comment: No need for that trailing semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

For a simple property with get and set, you can just put this in the class definition on its own:

```
property double Real;
```

and the compiler will sort out the backing store and accessors for you.